# Flutter Dropdown setState called during build

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, dropdown, textformfield

since Flutter Update 2.10.0 I get an error in combination of textformfield and dropdownbutton. The textformfield and the dropdownmenubutton are on the same screen.
If the textformfield has focus and I tap on dropdownbutton I get the following error: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
If I downgrade my flutter version back to 2.8.1 everything works fine.

Is there a known problem or a fix for this, or do I need to revise my code.

To avoid unnecessary source of errors I have used used standard textformfield and dropdownmenubutton.

Thanks in advance.

Greetings

Comment: You should add the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

try wrap with WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      //your code here
      setState(() {});
    });
```